# Auto create table rows at the beginning of each day

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, timestamp

I want registered users to login and enter a data(a number) every day. I want this to be inserted as rows in my database table each day. I can achieve this my using a query when the user enters the data. Now if a user misses a day, the query will not be executed and the specific row will not be created. But I want a row to be created with a default value in place of the data even if the user missed one day. Is there a way to achieve this in Mysql with time stamping or some thing (like an auto increment). And I am new with mysql. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have stated in the comments, I find these answers too complicated. So I used Cron jobs to run a PHP file every day at a time I set. This PHP file contains necessary code to check for users who did not enter the data that day and add the default data on their behalf.

In short, the solution I used for my problem above is '**CRON JOB**'.

Thanks again for other user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This would be wrong use of database.
Databases are not like paper forms. They intended to store only actual data, while everything missed have to be calculated at the output time.

In your case you don't need to create any rows.
But when selecting data for the particular day just use left join to fill missed rows.

Comment: This is another way of doing things. However you can speed up reports like this since you are essentially pre calculating the results. As a user that missed a day can never get that day back it might make sense to pre calculate the data and store it. If for example I have millions of users that log in daily calculating this might be expensive. If I had a few well it might not make sense to pre calculate. Depends on design. I did include a link for him to learn about left/right joins though.